# Does OtR require than IM applications remember multiple keys per contact?

Tags: instant-messaging

I noticed the [Guardian Project](https://guardianproject.info/) has developed a converter to [move your off-the-record messaging keys between different IM applications.](https://github.com/guardianproject/otrfileconverter)  I'm curious what happens if your using multiple off-the-record messaging clients without using their otrfileconverter program.  You must clearly verify each contact on each client and each contact must verify both your clients.  Can you expect your contat's clients to remember both your two different keys once you've been verified twice?  Is such behavior required by the standard?

Comment: To what standard are you referring? Can you post a link, please?

Comment: It would seem to be this protocol. http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/Protocol-v2-3.1.0.html

Comment: I think this is offtopic and too localised - you may be able to get more information from the Guardian Project themselves.

Comment: I'm unsure what "localized" means but the Guardian Project is obviously irrelevant.  I'm asking about the OtR protocol minopret linked.  I've answered it to my own satisfaction though : No.  In fact, doing so correctly would complicate security procedures significantly, although that might be a worthy goal.